# When can you have too many CTA's on your website?

Tags: website-design, user-behavior, user-expectation, landing-page, cta

I used to have a single CTA right below the page fold. I was advised to increase CTA section on my SaaS offering (https://divshow.bytebeacon.com). I thought that and a login button on a sticky navigation no top would be enough.

I decided to add another one right after a use case section. That is where My demo ends and for most people who are interested can login right after that section. However I've noticed people scrolling to pricing as well and then scrolling back up to CTA. Should I add another one after pricing now? IS that too many? How should we be thinking about CTA's on a website? There  can't be a golden bullet solution here, so anyone viewing my page, please do mention any specific advise you may have for my service.

Comment: Call To Action?

Answer (score 1):

You have very inconsistent CTA styles, I think the first step would be to standardise your button design pattern so that it is clear to the user what is a button and what is not. Some of them are too wide (but that is my personal opinion).

Comment: Was width the only concern on standardization? I think I fixed it by splitting the login and sit-up buttons. I felt I kept the overall design of buttons pretty consistent as they all use the same classes (rounded, solid color etc ).. Please let me know if you had other points in mind and the layout still feels inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

I think your sense is correct. Are you using a website template with a lot of sections you're trying to fill even though you might not have enough content for all of them?

For example, what is the value of the large Undraw hero image at the top? What if you kept the headline "Create your own presentations in under 5 minutes" and then put the How It Works content in that section? You could add a little more pricing info ("Start for free. Paid plans start at $10/month") and then the call to action buttons.

Also consider reducing the amount of content below the fold on your homepage -- particularly the Tell Me More section. You might have more success by moving that to an internal page, making the text larger, and making it more visually exciting with screenshots and interactivity.